# WordPress cant send emails even sendmail is working

Tags: php, wordpress, sendmail

I can send emails from the terminal using Sendmail
but I can't send an email within WordPress 
whats the problem?

PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u3 (cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in configuring php
you have to set -t -i flags in sendmail path like

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the PHP CLI version is different from the PHP web server, you can make sure about that.

Run below command in your terminal:

```
php -v
```

And get the PHP web server version with `phpinfo();`

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then you can use the correct PHP configuration for another that.

Please keep in mind, make sure you about your WordPress plugins, maybe you have installed a mail, such as WP SMTP or something else.

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.33-0+deb9u3
the same version